# NLTK could not tag the Punctuations in python2 program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use the `tahake` paraphrasing library and as per the syntax I need to tag the words in the sentence, which I partially did using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

text = '''The wife of a former U.S. president Bill Clinton Hillary Clinton visited China last Monday. Hillary Clinton wanted to visit China last month But postponed her plans till Monday last week. Hillary Clinton paid a visit to the People Republic of China on Monday. Last week the Secretary of State Ms Clinton visited Chinese officials.'''

sentences = re.split(r'(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s', text)
text = []
for sentence in sentences:    
    posTagges = pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
    text = text + [" ".join([k + '/' + v for k,v in posTagges])]
print text
```

And I got the following output:

> ['The/DT wife/NN of/IN a/DT former/JJ U.S./NNP president/NN Bill/NNP
>   Clinton/NNP Hillary/NNP Clinton/NNP visited/VBD China/NNP last/JJ
>   Monday/NNP ./.', 'Hillary/NNP Clinton/NNP wanted/VBD to/TO visit/VB
>   China/NNP last/JJ month/NN But/CC postponed/VBD her/PRP$ plans/NNS
>   till/VBP Monday/NNP last/JJ week/NN ./.', 'Hillary/JJ Clinton/NNP
>   paid/VBD a/DT visit/NN to/TO the/DT People/NNP Republic/NNP of/IN
>   China/NNP on/IN Monday/NNP ./.', 'Last/JJ week/NN the/DT Secretary/NNP
>   of/IN State/NNP Ms/NNP Clinton/NNP visited/VBD Chinese/JJ
>   officials/NNS ./.']

Now the problem what I am facing is in labelling the punctuations like `.` or others. what I see is `./.` whereas I require `./PUNCT`

Kindly help me, with the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.punctuation`

```
In [150]: string.punctuation
Out[150]: '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

[" ".join([k + '/PUCNT' if k in string.punctuation else k + '/' + v for k,v in posTagges])]
```